# Is there a more efficient way to write this iterative function?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I've been recently dealing with recursive and iterative functions. And I'm trying the following in the example below:

I have this recursive version of Pascal triangle:

```
def pascal_recursion(n):
    """ rekursive Version of Pascal-Function """
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    else:
        line = [1]
        old_line = pascal(n-1)
        for i in range(len(old_line)-1):
            line.append(old_line[i] + old_line[i+1])
        line += [1]
    return line
```

And now I want to write the iterative version of it without calling the function which turned to be more efficient in the Fibonacci-series. So if the input was *pascal_iterative (4)*, then it should give the fourth line of the pascal triangle. But unfortunately I always get the same result of the previous line.

```
    def pascal_iterative (n):
        """iterative version of Pascal-Function"""
        oldline, newline = [1], [1, 1]
        if n == 1:
            return [1]
        for i in range(n-1):
            oldline, newline = newline, [oldline[0]] + [oldline[i] + oldline[i+1] for i in range(len(oldline) - 1)] + [oldline[-1]]
        return newline
```

So, any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each line of pascal's triangle is computed from the previous one, but here you're computing the new `newline` from the old `oldline`, rather than from the old `newline`. There should be no need for both `oldline` and `newline`, you just have one line which you replace by the newline on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In the second-last line of the function, change all the `oldline`s to `newline`s:

```py
def pascal_iterative (n):
    oldline, newline = [1], [1, 1]
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    for i in range(n-1):
        oldline, newline = newline, [newline[0]] + [newline[i] + newline[i+1] for i in range(len(newline) - 1)] + [newline[-1]]
    return newline
```

This works properly for me.

Furthermore this can be simplified as you don't need both oldline and newline:

```py
def pascal_iterative (n):
    line = [1]
    for i in range(n-1):
        line = [line[0]] + [line[i] + line[i+1] for i in range(len(line) - 1)] + [line[-1]]
    return line
```